# What to do with wire shielding before attaching the plug?

Tags: wire, wire-terminals

As far as I understand, the wire shielding is for [noise control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shielded_cable).

**Question**

I cut a USB wire in half and am going to apply a 2 pin JST connector to the power & ground. Do I cut the wire shield back out of the way or should it connect in with the ground?

**Bonus Question**

I recently saw a 5 wire cable with 6 pins at the end so I assume the last wire is the shielding. Is this a common approach? The device was a [Microsoft Kinect 360](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinect#Kinect_for_Xbox_360) (v1)

Comment: It's better to have the shield connected to protective earth/chassis on both sides. If you don't have it on one side - that's a design failure (but not a fatal one in most cases).

Comment: look also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_shielding,     https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday_cage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, it depends on the application and if your device(s) are in a high noise environment (machinery,high switching noise from components, etc.). Also, are you sending data down this USB line?

But to answer your main question, this shield would normally go to a chassis ground, on both ends. If connected to another ground, it would cause a ground loop which, in practice, aren't ideal. These can be hazardous in some situations. Eliminate multiple grounds when possible.

Comment: http://www.rane.com/note151.html

Explains some of the common practices.

Comment: Interesting. I'm only sending power + ground, no data. If I leave the shield disconnected where I cut the wire will that render it useless?

Comment: If it's for something that's a hobby project, I wouldn't worry about connecting/securing it. For my personal projects where I just need to power something, not having it connected won't harm anything. 

If you plan to use it out in the field, it's good to connect that shield to a chassis ground as mentioned before.